# lock a table in sql server 2008 after select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a main currency table. Which has two fields, one currency Type and currency value. User can not be changed once a user start working with the DB. I need to lock my Currency table through SQL Server 2008 Query once user select one value.
Can any one help me or suggest me for DB LOCK query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOLOCK` for your objects.

For example :

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Orders WITH(NOLOCK) where UserName = 'VadaVici'
```

Comment: Either I've misunderstood the question or OP misunderstood this solution but using `NOLOCK` in a select by no means prevents other users from changing the table.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem on a table in our database. Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299730/sql-server-management-studio-table-locked-due-to-select-statement) and it worked for us:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WITH (TABLOCKX);
```

The table will be locked until a `COMMIT TRANSACTION` or `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` is executed.

Hope it helps somebody in the future...